# Convert Place object to Address (Google Maps)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I need to convert Place object (which I get from PlacePicker) to Address. For this purpose I use Geocoder object:

```
    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
    List<Address> addressList = appContext.getGeocoder().getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
    if (!addressList.isEmpty()) {
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
}
```

But sometimes Geocoder returns wrong object. I tried to search by name, but sometimes it doesn't find anything. Also each place on map has unique id:

```
place.getId()
```

Is there any appropriate way to get RIGHT address guaranteed?

Comment: Are you asking for the Address object or a human-readable address string? 

Since you already have the `Place` object, it will contain the `placeId`. You can now get the address of the specific place by using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service). Place Details API will require the `placeid` and return an output with a `formatted_address` attribute.